# 'X Is not a function' in CommonJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I've got the following code I transformed from a Trypescript, ESM-syntax based file to a Javascript, CJS-syntax file.

```
const apiClientFactory = require("@vue-storefront/core");

function onCreate(settings) {
  return {
    config: settings,
    client: {},
  };
}

const getPrice = () => {
  console.log("$55,98")
}

const { createApiClient } = apiClientFactory({
  onCreate,
  api: {
    getPrice,
  },
});

module.exports = {
  createApiClient,
};
```

I can not seem to find if the error "apiClientFactory is not a function" originates from old ESM-based code. Or that the function isn't called properly. However, apiClientFactory is correctly imported (ESM syntax)

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `apiClientFactory` after the `require()`? I bet it's an object with lots of stuff in it, not a function.

Comment: It should probably be `const { apiClientFactory } = require("@vue-storefront/core");`

Comment: @ChrisG That seemed to be it. Thanks Lad

Comment: @Pointy Ty for pointing that out, learning more everyday :)

Comment: Note that `const vueStorefront = require("@vue-storefront/core" );` and `const apiClientFactory = vueStorefront.apiClientFactory;` would've worked, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with this?

Because the whole Vue Storefront project uses TypeScript, so I recommend you to use it and follow the procedures and code standards that we are using.

To find a good example on the API please check the code for the integrations of Magento or Vendure.

Comment: Thanks! Filip already helped me in your Discord server :) He recommended me to use this syntax